# How do you run Integration test to GRPC Client and Server together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have an `Asp.net Core 6` Web api.

I have a `GRPC` Client which calls a `GRPC` Server and I want to perform an Integration test with `xUnit` which involves both of them.

**I want the Client to call the Server and return a response and make assertions to the response.**

I saw MSDN examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and I saw this answer on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944216/aspnetcore-integration-testing-multiple-webapplicationfactory-instances/65050516#65050516).

Based on these 2 examples I came up with the following test class:

```
public class ItemsTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<FirstProject.Program>>,
                           IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<SecondProject.Program>>
{

    private readonly HttpClient _firstProjectClient;

    public ItemsTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<FirstProject.Program> firstFactory,
                       CustomWebApplicationFactory<SecondProject.Program> secondFactory)
    {
         var secondProjectClient = = secondFactory.CreateClient();
         var grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(secondProjectClient.BaseAddress, new 
         GrpcChannelOptions() 
         {
             HttpClient = secondProjectClient;
         });

         var grpcClient = new ItemsServiceClient(grpcChannel);

         var mockGrpcClientFactory = new Mock<GrpcClientFactory>();
         
         mockGrpcClientFactory
              .SetUp(x=>x.CreateClient<ItemsServiceClient>(It.IsAny<string>())
              .Returns(grpcClient);

        _firstProjectClient = firstFactory
                           .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                           {
                                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                                {
                                    services.AddTransient(x => mockGrpcClientFactory);
                                });
                           })
                           .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
                           {
                               AllowAutoRedirect = false
                           });

    }
}

[Fact]
public void FirstTest()
{
   //Act 
   var reponse = await _firstProjectClient.GetAsync("/Items");

}
```

This above code works. It truly goes as far as the second project and returns the information.
**My question is: is it optimal? Does anyone see any flaws with this implementation?**

Comment: IMHO, this level of integration should be tested by end-to-end tests, not integration. In integration tests, you should mock the external dependencies, in other words when testing project A, mock the project B responses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Integration tests evaluate an app's components on a broader level than unit tests. The gRPC app is hosted in TestServer, an in-memory test server from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost package.

A unit test library starts the gRPC app and then gRPC services are tested using the gRPC client.

The sample code contains infrastructure to make integration testing possible:

- The GrpcTestFixture class configures the ASP.NET Core host and starts the gRPC app in an in-memory test server.
- The IntegrationTestBase class is the base type that integration tests inherit from. It contains the fixture state and APIs for creating a gRPC client to call the gRPC app.

See: [AspNetCore.Docs/aspnetcore/grpc/test-services/sample/Tests/Server/IntegrationTests/](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/grpc/test-services/sample/Tests/Server/IntegrationTests)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this sample for Integration tests.  However, I am trying to make something broader than this. I want to use the WebApplicationFactory as described here to call the Api of the first project and get to the second project.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0