# Why am I getting "Unable to resolve service" errors when running 2 WebApplicationFactory classes in testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit.net, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to run the following integration test using xUnit in Net Core 7.  (Note that for now I am just trying to spin up 2 webapplicationfactory for the test just now)

```cs
namespace mNet.FileServer.Commands.Ui.Api.Tests.Integration.StoredFileTypeEndpoint;
public class NewStoredFileTypeEndpointTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task New_CreatesNewStoredFileType_WhenDataIsValid()
    {
        // Arrange
        var commandServer = new WebApplicationFactory<IFileServerCommandsApiMarker>();
        var commandHttpClient = commandServer.CreateClient();

        var queryServer = new WebApplicationFactory<IFileServerQueriesApiMarker>();
        var queryHttpClient = queryServer.CreateClient();

        
       
        // Act
        await Task.Delay(3000);
     

        // Assert
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

When I try and run the test with only one webapplicationfactory (it doesn't matter which as I have tried both), the test runs successfully.  However, why I try and run both as per the code above, I get the following error:

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommandHandler'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommandHandler'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypes.NewStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<.ctor>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\dcmea\OneDrive\mNet Microservices\mNet.FileServer\mNet.FileServer.Queries.Ui.MinimalApi\Program.cs:line 42
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypes.DeleteStoredFileTypeCommandHandler'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #2) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommandHandler'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.ChangeStoredFileTypeName.ChangeStoredFileTypeNameCommandHandler'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #3) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommand,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.Responses.StoredFileTypeCommandResponse]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommandHandler'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'mNet.Common.Core.Application.Contracts.Persistence.EventSourcing.IEventSourcingHandler`2[mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Domain.Aggregates.StoredFileTypes.StoredFileType,mNet.FileServer.Shared.Core.Domain.StoredFileTypes.ValueObjects.StoredFileTypeId]' while attempting to activate 'mNet.FileServer.Commands.Core.Application.Features.StoredFileTypes.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtension.AddStoredFileTypeFileExtensionCommandHandler'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---
```

I am trying to do an integration test between 2 microservices similar to Maurits Moeys answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701369/21137253) which doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

**Update:** Having played around with some of MediatR calls, this is bit which seems to be causing the problem:

```cs
services.AddMediatR(cfg => 
cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
);
```

Removing it lets the test above build (without any logic) but the apps don't work as they need the services.  I don't really want to have to register every single assembly 1 by 1, but not sure what else I can do.

Comment: You can debug the test and look at the exception details inside the AggregateException. The exception trace you have shared does not explain the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @Chetan.  I have updated the error message in the original question